# Is "enough" after a noun grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

On Page 80 of V. Frankl's [Man's Search for Meaning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009U9S6FI), this sentence occurs:

> We were the only two in camp who had strength enough to do the job.

As far as I know we can use [enough as a determiner before a noun](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/enough). The work in English is a translation from German by Ilse Lasch. Has the translator made a mistake here by bringing *enough* after *strength*?

Comment: It's fine. "Enough" has the syntactic peculiarity of being able to appear as post-head modifier.

Comment: To His Coy Mistress BY ANDREW MARVELL Had we but world enough and time,/This coyness, lady, were no crime./We would sit down, and think which way/To walk, and pass our long love’s day. (...)

Comment: [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strength+enough&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrength%20enough%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cstrength%20enough%3B%2Cc1) shows that the usage of _strength enough_ has declined since the early 19th century, but still exists. Admittedly, some of the examples are reprints of earlier works.

Comment: Had we time enough we could quote as well from Neil Leach (2005), from. Amin Maalouf (2002) and many others. POST-MODERNITY AS A CULTURAL WEAPON by PV ALMEIDA · 2015

Comment: Had I wealth enough, I might consider shorting Tesla.

Comment: And this Ngram tells a slightly different story: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had%20strength%20enough%20to%2Chad%20enough%20strength%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20strength%20enough%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20enough%20strength%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chad%20strength%20enough%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20enough%20strength%20to%3B%2Cc0]